# Remove Values in Column Without Removing Anything Else

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqypw.png)
However, in col4, I have some repeating values that I want to delete but keep the first repeating value so that my data frame looks like this:[modified dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Sdz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only replace them to empty string:

```
df['col4'] = df['col4'].mask(df['col4'].duplicated(), '')

#thank you Corralien for alternative
df.loc[df['col4'].duplicated(), 'col4'] = ''
```

Or to missing values:

```
df['col4'] = df['col4'].mask(df['col4'].duplicated())
```